# Microsoft Bot Framework - Python - Sometimes i get a "Unauthorized" error when using Microsoft Teams

Tags: python, frameworks, bots, microsoft-teams, azure-bot-service

Written a Python app using aiohttp based on the MS examples, working allover, nothing special.
Python bot service is running in production on my own server behind a firewall on a K8S cluster..... no issues so far.

We also configured the "Azure bot" as described by MS without issues, MS Teams channel activated, App uploaded and published. Yeah, working! Cool!

But, unpredictable after a minute or a hour or a day i get the following error messages when sending request through the Teams app. Important notice, usign the WebChat through the Azure Webportal is working!!!!!???? Anybody else hit such a issue?

```
│ Traceback (most recent call last):                                                                                                                         │
│   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/botbuilder/core/bot_adapter.py", line 128, in run_pipeline                                                 │
│     return await self._middleware.receive_activity_with_status(                                                                                            │
│   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/botbuilder/core/middleware_set.py", line 69, in receive_activity_with_status                               │
│     return await self.receive_activity_internal(context, callback)                                                                                         │
│   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/botbuilder/core/middleware_set.py", line 79, in receive_activity_internal                                  │
│     return await callback(context)                                                                                                                         │
│   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/botbuilder/core/activity_handler.py", line 70, in on_turn                                                  │
│     await self.on_message_activity(turn_context)                                                                                                           │
│   File "/app/bots/teams_conversation_bot.py", line 99, in on_message_activity                                                                              │
│     await self._send_unknown_request_activity(turn_context)                                                                                                │
│   File "/app/bots/teams_conversation_bot.py", line 103, in _send_unknown_request_activity                                                                  │
│     await turn_context.send_activity(                                                                                                                      │
│   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/botbuilder/core/turn_context.py", line 174, in send_activity                                               │
│     result = await self.send_activities([activity_or_text])                                                                                                │
│   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/botbuilder/core/turn_context.py", line 226, in send_activities                                             │
│     return await self._emit(self._on_send_activities, output, logic())                                                                                     │
│   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/botbuilder/core/turn_context.py", line 304, in _emit                                                       │
│     return await logic                                                                                                                                     │
│   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/botbuilder/core/turn_context.py", line 221, in logic                                                       │
│     responses = await self.adapter.send_activities(self, output)                                                                                           │
│   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/botbuilder/core/bot_framework_adapter.py", line 735, in send_activities                                    │
│     raise error                                                                                                                                            │
│   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/botbuilder/core/bot_framework_adapter.py", line 720, in send_activities                                    │
│     response = await client.conversations.reply_to_activity(                                                                                               │
│   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/botframework/connector/aio/operations_async/_conversations_operations_async.py", line 529, in reply_to_act │
│     raise models.ErrorResponseException(self._deserialize, response)                                                                                       │
│ botbuilder.schema._models_py3.ErrorResponseException: Operation returned an invalid status code 'Unauthorized'
```

I have to restart the container (to the Python bot) and to delete the MS teams chat to fix this, uncool :(

Already tried to get some more information from logs and scraped the known locations for answers.

Comment: Are you able to identify what endpoint is giving you a 401 error? The fact that the web chat works suggests that the container is running and accessible. This may be a Teams-specific issue if only the Teams app experiences this problem. Out of curiosity, does the error reproduce in the Teams web interface through a browser?

Comment: Behaviour of Teams is the same independet of the client (web or desktop tested with different devices and accounts). Webchat and Telegram channel working without any problems. Looks like a Teams<>Azure Bot Services issue but i don't see any error message anywhere.

Comment: Hmm....I have two other ideas you can try. The easy one is to reach out to Teams support and see if they can help identify the authentication issue. The other thing you might try is deploying the bot outside your cluster in a test environment and see if the issue reproduces. It seems likely that, for some reason, Teams is unable to reliably connect to your cluster.

Comment: THX AP01, Support wasn't really helpful. I got better recommendations from Stackoverflow :)
Regarding the "outside your cluster", my code is already running outside of Azure. Or did i understand that wrong? Anyway, it's a good idea to run the app hostet on Azure to see if there are any issues. Can't imagine but who knows....

Comment: I meant outside the K8s cluster, not outside Azure. That said, if an Azure App Service is something you can try, it might give us some data points.